# Importing a table from the web to Excel using VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping, dom-events

Wrote some basic VBA that connects to a website, inputs a username and password to that site, logs in, then copies a table  and pastes it into excel. Now I realised that my table contains graphics with links. Instead of copying the table previously mentioned, I want to follow these links individually and copy the tables these link to, into Excel instead.

However, these graphics in the web table don't contain individual direct hyperlinks. I viewed the web page source, and it contains Javascript. (See below)

```
 <a href="#" onclick="var a=function(){javascript:window.open('','ProcStatus','top=50,left=' +     (screen.width - 750) + ',width=700,height=500,resizable,status,scrollbars');};var b=function()    {if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('MainPage'),        {'j_id202:319:j_id208':'j_id202:319:j_id208'},'ProcStatus');}return false};return (a()==false) ?     false : b();"><img src="image.gif" alt="View Details" style="border: 0;" title="View Details" /></a>
```

I can see the functions these call in the source code, and bearing in mind that I know zero about Javascript, how would my VBA code go about executing/opening these links, and then moving on to the second row in the table, to the next link? Basically, how do I populate the variables required by the `onclick` event, and then activate that hyperlink to open the new web page?

And then every subsequent link in that table?

Answer (score 1):

You can call a JavaScript function from VBA by using the following:

```
Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("functionName()", "JavaScript")
```

In your case it would look like:

```
Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("var a=function(){javascript:window.open('','ProcStatus','top=50,left=' +     (screen.width - 750) + ',width=700,height=500,resizable,status,scrollbars');};var b=function()    {if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('MainPage'),        {'j_id202:319:j_id208':'j_id202:319:j_id208'},'ProcStatus');}return false};return (a()==false) ?     false : b();", "JavaScript")
```

Alternatively, you could also instruct your macro to click on the link using DOM methods. You will have to dig through the source code to find out exactly where the element is located, but in general you code will be along the following lines:

```
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")[3].click
```

Where 3 is the index of the array of "a" elements.

You don't need to know a whole lot of javascript to be effective at webscraping but it helps to know some basic DOM methods.

- *document*.getElementsByTagName -- finds elements with a given tagname, such as `table`, `a`, `td`, `tr`, `div`, etc.
- *document*.getElementsByName -- finds elements with a given name
- *document*.getElementById -- finds elements with a given id
- *element*.innerText -- returns the text of an element
- *element*.innerHTML -- returns the HTML of an element
- *element*.click -- clicks on an element
- *element*.getAttribute("attribute") -- returns value of given attribute, like `href` or `style`

Comment: I probably was being too nieve by trying to just plugin what you said would be my solution.It spits out an error.
Would I possibly need to set other variables in order to have the "ExecScript" execute the function passed in above?

I couldn't really follow the second part. The source code contains a few tables, each with about 50 rows. I can select the table I want easily enough, but other than copy it, I'm not sure what the next steps would be?

The actual code that I am exexcuting / the javascript......is that generic? I have no idea what its trying to do? Is it obvious to others?

Comment: Yeah, VBA doesn't really like all the extra characters that javascript introduces. VBA reads those single quotes as a comment delimiter. It will probably be better just to have the macro click on the element. The best way to learn how to use DOM methods is to open up the Chrome javascript console (Ctrl + Shift + J) and try out different pieces of code. Grabbing tables from web pages is pretty easy once you learn some basic javascript.

Comment: If you send me the website you're trying to scrape I could help you get started.

Comment: When I extract the string in VBA, it seems to look OK. The quotes are all intact. Anything wrapped entirely in double quotes is normally Ok and is treated like a string.
The Console property box does looks pretty helpful - but once again, Ive no idea what it's telling me. 

The website I'm extracting from is pretty confidential and password protected. Im trying to google something similar but not having much look so far. Would screenprints be useful? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, this is the page source code, edited.The section in Notifications called "this is what i need", are the links i need to scrape from [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22557385/JSPageSource.html)

Comment: `ie.document.getElementById("panelNotifications").getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(3).Children(0).Click`

Comment: To iterate through each link in that table just change `getElementsByTagName("tr")(0)` to `getElementsByTagName("tr")(i)` and iterate for i = 0 to 10

Comment: That worked.I can open the subpage. Im having trouble accessing the data on this subpage? Basically in a large table, there are about 50 fields. I just need to extract handful? Is there a line of code i can use? Do I need to direct the code to look at theis subpage. Table looks like this and i need to extract the value 123456.    '<tr><td class="LeftColumn"><span class="Testo_Label">Code Number </span>
</td><td class="RightColumn"><span id="VRN_3" "Testo_Output">123456 </span></td></tr>'

Comment: I tried using a variety of the DOM methods you mentioned above, but Im just getting errors about "object not set or object required. tnx.

Comment: Well if you want that number specifically, you could do something like this: `document.getElementById("VRN_3").innerText`

Comment: Cheers.  I found some code. 
'For Each ie In winShell.Windows
    If Right(ie.LocationURL, 14) = urlToLookFor Then
       ie.Visible = False
       Set retVal = ie
       
        Exit For
    End If
Next'  
which seemed to do the trick. It meant i could point to a second Internet Explorer pop up window and then tab between them. worked a treat. cheers for your help