# Can't correctly lanuch JS code on webpage - VBA script

Tags: javascript, vba, click, execute

I'm working on a script that will go through each email in Outlook Web Access. Messages are stored in a table, available via click on the title of the message (as seen below).

```
<table><tr><td nowrap class="frst">carrie.stevens@u...&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap class="sc frst"><h1><a href="#" onClick="onClkRdMsg(this, 'IPM.Note', 0, 0);">Message 1</a></h1>&nbsp;</td><td nowrap class="frst">1/11/2011&nbsp;12:16 PM&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap>Doodle&nbsp;</td><td nowrap class="sc"><h1><a href="#" onClick="onClkRdMsg(this, 'IPM.Note', 1, 0);">Message 2</a></h1>&nbsp;</td><td nowrap>1/11/2011&nbsp;8:29 AM&nbsp;</td></tr>`
</table>
```

The problem is that there is a piece of java script used to open each message

```
onClkRdMsg(this, 'IPM.Note', 0, 0)
onClkRdMsg(this, 'IPM.Note', 1, 0)
```

What I tried is:

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

'The code requires references to the following:
'1 Microsoft Internet Controls
'2. Microsoft HTML Object Library

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer

URL_fold = "mywebpage.com"
oBrowser.navigate URL_fold
oBrowser.Visible = True
    Do
    ' Wait till the Browser is loaded
    Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    HTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript "onClkRdMsg(this, 'IPM.Note', 1, 0)"

Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
    'Debug.Assert Err = 0
    Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

but it doesn't work. Neither does:

```
For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("h1")
        oHTML_Element.Click
Next
```

What am I doing wrong? Your help would be higly appreciated, as my attempts don't working - JS code is not triggered after webpage is loaded.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me for programatically click 'Message 1'. 
*When testing be carefull to enable script execution.*

```
Private Const URL As String = "C:/Temp/HTML/HTMLPage1.html"
Sub test()
        Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
        Dim Document As HTMLDocument

        Set Browser = New InternetExplorer
        Browser.Visible = True
        Browser.navigate URL

        Do While Browser.Busy And Not Browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set Document = Browser.Document

        Dim tds As IHTMLElementCollection
        Dim anchors As IHTMLElementCollection
        Dim tdElement As IHTMLElement
        Dim anchorElement As IHTMLElement

        Set tds = Document.getElementsByClassName("sc")
        For Each tdElement In tds
            Set anchors = tdElement.getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each anchorElement In anchors
                If (anchorElement.innerText = "Message 1") Then
                    anchorElement.Click
                    GoTo Quit:
                End If
            Next anchorElement
        Next tdElement

        Quit:
        Browser.Quit
        Set Document = Nothing
        Set Browser = Nothing
    End Sub
```

> HTMLPage1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function onClkRdMsg(a, b, c, d) {
            alert('Clicked: [onClkRdMsg]...');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap class="frst">carrie.stevens@u...&nbsp;</td>
            <td nowrap class="sc frst">
                <h1>
                    <a href="#" onclick="onClkRdMsg(this, 'IPM.Note', 0, 0);">Message 1</a>
                </h1>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td nowrap class="frst">1/11/2011&nbsp;12:16 PM&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap>Doodle&nbsp;</td>
            <td nowrap class="sc">
                <h1>
                    <a href="#" onclick="onClkRdMsg(this, 'IPM.Note', 1, 0);">Message 2</a>
                </h1>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td nowrap>1/11/2011&nbsp;8:29 AM&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have two problems: 
1. The code gets stuck at line "Set tds = Document.getElementsByClassName("sc")" (Code error: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method)
2. 'Message 1' and 'Message 2' are going to vary - these are going to be messages' subjects. Can I trigger JS action directly somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Below code DOES NOT WORK fine - I'll update once I'll figure out the correct answer:

```
Private Const URL As String = "C:/HTMLPage1.html"
Sub test()
        Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
        Dim Document As HTMLDocument

        Set Browser = New InternetExplorer
        Browser.Visible = True
        Browser.navigate URL

        Do While Browser.Busy And Not Browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set Document = Browser.Document
        Document.parentWindow.execScript "onClkRdMsg(this, 'IPM.Note', 0, 0)"

Quit:
        Browser.Quit
        Set Document = Nothing
        Set Browser = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Thank you Daniel!

Comment: Ok, when it works than it's fine. But what is 'this' when the script is executed on parent window? Hmm maybe this is not used in the function 'onClkRdMsg' at all? When executed on anchor then 'this' should refer to that anchor, but on window? It confuses me a little :-). And there are another parameters: 'IPM.Note' and then two numbers. Do you handle these params sommehow?

Comment: Regarding the execution of the code, I took the idea from http://stackoverflow.com/a/13805106/1516813 and I'm not sure I do understand it in 100% to be honest if it works correctly. I'll check it on the desired webpage tomorrow (I have no access to it right now) and will let you know. With sample HTMLPage1.html on my computer it works fine. And yes - I'll handle one of these paremeters incrementing it with something like:
Document.parentWindow.execScript ("onClkRdMsg(this, 'IPM.Note'," & counter & ", 0)").
Regards!

Comment: Ok, I tested it in desired webpage (Outlook Web Access - you can test it for free at http://www.123together.com/d/exchange_hosting_demo.xhtml) and this code is not working correctly - I edited the answer and I'm trying to find a solution.